# не удалось найти указанный пакет SDK "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly"

Tags: visual-studio, sdk, blazor, настройки, assembly

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вывод: `не удалось найти указанный пакет SDK "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly"`

*что и откуда установить, чтоб устранить ошибку в загрузке приложения?*

[тут вот были предложены ссылки на sdk](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/blazor-webassembly-3-2-0-now-available/) я установила [7 и 6](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download)
при установке `VS` я галочки поставила на все, что использую

вот [по этой ссылке первая в гугл](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.AOT/) стала загружать через консоль, и там вышла другая [ссылка](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0), что мол идите оттуда скачайте, я скачала
`sdk`, но у меня все равно все та же ошибка, подскажите что я пропустила

я удалила и заново установила Визуал Студио, ошибка не уходит, и все ссылки в гугл на первой странице я вынужденно прочитала, так и не нашла в чем кроется моя ошибка. к тому же, когда я создаю новый проект, не удается его запустить. У меня такое впервые, возможно ли это связанно с Виндовс11 или все таки какие то настройки пропустила ? [вот тоже пишет про этот sdk](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/17919)

а тут как то настроить нужно ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я форматировала один из компьютеров и теперь никак не получается работать даже с визуал студио, я вот создала тестовый проект и даже его не могу запустить
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[по этой ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65206161/net-5-azure-pipeline-the-sdk-microsoft-net-sdk-blazorwebassembly-specified) говорят о смене пакетов? таски применяют

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я много читала (*хоть и не оч люблю, поэтому заняло 12 дней для решения этого вопроса*), чтоб понять где ошибка, много разных статей, док-ов.

Причина как стало известно => при форматировании бывает неверная распаковка некоторых `sdk` и это может дать сбой для компиляции, где то советовали давать настройку в зависимости от желаемой среды, а где то говорили, скачать дополнительные пакеты, скачать еще что то, я пробовала много разных вариантов...безуспешно.

...подумав, я решила ПЕРЕ**форматировать комп**, ну и в результате, я успешно смогла клонировать/компилировать/запустить проект блазор и прочие и **вопрос закрыт.**